# Generalizing a typedef of a structure per user .c file (making a generic stackdata type)

Tags: stack, typedef

I'm referencing the book, "Data structures in c" by Noel Kalicharan.  In example Program P4.4, it says:

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef struct {
char ch;
} StackData;

#include <stack.h>
```

The reason the #include of stack.h comes after the typedef is because stack.h depends on StackData.  Are there any recommendations about a better way of accomplishing this goal of achieving a more portable/generalized StackData?  (Other users may want to include stack.h but have a different datatype for their StackData.)  I don't particularly care for the way the typedef has to precede the #include.

Is there a better/neater way of accomplishing this goal?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The better way is to use templates, but I guess you haven't learnt it yet.

For now, it will be neater to put the struct definition in a header file and include it.

like this:

```
//filename: StackData.h
#ifndef  __StackData__HDR__
#define  __StackData__HDR__

typedef struct {
char ch;
} StackData;

#endif
```

then your file can be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "StackData.h"
#include <stack.h>
```

Comment: I appreciate your feedback.  I am currently coding in C (Microchip's embedded XC compiler). Microchip does have a C++ compiler for their 32 bit products only, so I might be able to leverage templates for those families.   If templates were excluded, I still like your solution better than what's presented in Kalicharan's book for this example.  Many thanks.

Comment: I tried to +1 for this answer, but I don't have the credibility the system requires to allow me to do so.  If someone else could do this I'd appreciate it.